# Problema de regressão vs Time Series prediction problem

Tags: regressão, séries-temporais

Viva.

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre um problema de regressão e um de time series prediction. Acho que a regressão é usada para perceber como é que as variáveis independentes interferem com a variável dependente. Estou certo?

Comment: Você está modelando isso em código? Teria um trecho para mostrar? Ou é uma dúvida conceitual sobre estatística? Nesse caso, parece *off-topic* aqui no site.

Comment: Não é sobre código porque ainda não cheguei lá. Primeiro à que entender a teoria para depois passar ao código. Por isso para já é uma dúvida teórica :)

Comment: Hm, então, nada contra perguntas teóricas, mas como é sobre estatística e não programação, continuo achando off-topic.

Comment: Também me parece off-topic.